# Snapping multiple vertices but picking which one is primary

Tags: snapping

I'm having trouble figuring out how to snap multiple vertices but selecting by which one the position of all of them is adjusted.

Right now I can't be precise because I'm not able to align edge to edge because of this. I'm coming from 3DS Max and that was something I was able to do by just picking which vertex is main one.

[image: I would like to be able to snap this group of vertices so that the edges of the selected object and the objects on the left align.]

Comment: For your object to snap, in the Snap options, you have Target > Closest / Center / Median / Active, and you use your cursor to point out the vertex to stick to

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit more? Because when I move the cursor to the vertex I want to snap to, it snaps the top vertex to it, not the far left ones.

Comment: None of those options make any difference.

Comment: I guess what you call main vertex is the Active one in Blender

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the vertex you want to snap, in the *Snap* options, you have the choice between *Target > Closest / Center / Median / Active*. To point out the vertex you want to snap to, use your cursor.

[image]

For example *Active* will snap the last vertex you've selected.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so so much! :D It finally worked, I needed to select the last vertices one by one and not just group select them all. Thanks once again! :)

Comment: or select them all then click twice on the one you want to make active

Answer (score 4):

If you set your 'Snap To' to *Vertex* and 'Snap With' to *Active*, then the active element will be snapped to vertices, carrying the other (selected but not active) elements with it.

In Vertex mode, that means you're snapping the active vertex to vertices. In Face mode, the center of the active face, Edge mode, the center of the active edge. The active element is the last selected.

@moonboots has illustrated it nicely -  the wording of the interface has been made a little clearer in the upcoming version 2.83.

Comment: Thank you! ^^ The combination of how both of you worded your responses helped me figure out that I needed to select vertices manually and it worked.